# Can different centrals connect to the same peripheral in iOS Bluetooth LE 4.2?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

In iOS Core Bluetooth, which support Bluetooth 4.2, if an app is configured to act as a BLE peripheral, can multiple BLE centrals connect to the app at the same time? If so, is only one CBPeripheralManager or multiple CBPepripheralManagers needed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. CoreBluetooth can handle multiple connections from different centrals. You only need one instance of CBPeripheralManager to achieve this. The read/write requests will be delivered to your CBPeripheralManagerDelegate from the OS.

Comment: I believe the GATT standard says you can only have one connection at a time. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062047/1161906): "a BLE peripheral can only be connected to one central device (a mobile phone, etc.) at a time". Can you elaborate?